# pyspark UDF: Error while applying min, max to a list of floats in the data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

One of the column in my dataframe is as below. It has each row with a list of floats. I am trying to normalize it by subtracting the min and dividing the max.

```
X_Item_No
[0, 0, 0.09, 0.01, 0.013, 0.016, 0.018, 0.021]
[0, 0, 0.04, 0.31, 0.313, 0.216, 0.618, 0.028]
```

Code I tried:

```
   array_min = udf(lambda x: float(np.min(x)), FloatType())
   array_max = udf(lambda x: float(np.max(x)), FloatType())
    
def test(cols, min, max):
  return [(ele - min)/max for ele in cols]

df=(df.withColumn('X_col_min',array_min('X_Item_No'))
   .withColumn('X_col_max',array_max('X_Item_No'))))

    #display(df)
```

I am getting the below error when I try to apply the above UDF and display the dataframe. The trace back is a bunch of scala errors and is not useful for me to debug.

```
PythonException: 'TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType''
```

Then apply the 'test' function to the min and max

```
df2 = (df.withColumn('X_Item_No_new', f.udf(test, ArrayType(FloatType()))(df['X_Item_No'], df['X_col_min'],df['X_col_max']))
```

Comment: any reason why using UDF instead of pyspark's `array_min` and `array_max` functions?

Comment: @AdibP Wanted to create a lambda function to apply on every row which is a list of floats. Any suggestions on better way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column `X_Item_No` seems to have null values. Because of `np.min([None])` returns *None*, converting *None* to *float* will throw that exception.

To get min and max values in an array, it's better to use spark's `array_min` and `array_max` functions instead of using udf.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([[[0., 0., 0.09, 0.01, 0.013, 0.016, 0.018, 0.021]],
                            [[0., 0., 0.04, 0.31, 0.313, 0.216, 0.618, 0.028]]], schema="X_Item_No array<float>")
df = (df
      .withColumn('X_col_min', F.array_min('X_Item_No'))
      .withColumn('X_col_max', F.array_max('X_Item_No')))
df.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
|X_Item_No                                         |X_col_min|X_col_max|
+--------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
|[0.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.01, 0.013, 0.016, 0.018, 0.021]|0.0      |0.09     |
|[0.0, 0.0, 0.04, 0.31, 0.313, 0.216, 0.618, 0.028]|0.0      |0.618    |
+--------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
```

If you are using spark version 2.4+, you can use SQL `TRANSFORM` to apply a function to every values in an array.

```
df = df.withColumn('X_Item_No_new', F.expr("TRANSFORM(X_Item_No, value -> (value - X_col_min) / X_col_max)"))
df.show(truncate=False)

+--------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|X_Item_No                                         |X_col_min|X_col_max|X_Item_No_new                                                                                                         |
+--------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[0.0, 0.0, 0.09, 0.01, 0.013, 0.016, 0.018, 0.021]|0.0      |0.09     |[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.11111110421242565, 0.14444444168497025, 0.17777777915751486, 0.1999999834431549, 0.2333333209156995]|
|[0.0, 0.0, 0.04, 0.31, 0.313, 0.216, 0.618, 0.028]|0.0      |0.618    |[0.0, 0.0, 0.06472492069350876, 0.5016181504446381, 0.5064725053309027, 0.349514588623286, 1.0, 0.045307446896647376] |
+--------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your solution worked. But I'm new to using spark (3.0). I would like to know some more info on how the array_min and array_max functions handles NULL values and numpy doesnt.

Comment: sorry, did a bit of misleading there. I've edited my answer.